# Force vertical scroll bar on animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a div that animated from `height: 0` to `height: 80%` (80% of the body) and sometimes the content in this appearing div will be bigger than the div, requiring a scroll bar.

Problem is the scroll bar isn't apparant when the animation is running, and it only appears when it needs to after the animation. (kinda a good thing really)

But I'm being picky because I'm adding the final touches to my site and when the scroll bar randomly appears, it shifts the content left and it just looks funny.

So I want the scroll bar to be there all the time regardless. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation library must be setting `overflow: hidden` on the outer element, which is why the scrollbar disappears.

Try wrapping the content in one more div:

```
<!-- the outer element; pass this one to the animation lib -->
<div>
    <!-- the scroll bar will appear on this element -->
    <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 100%">
        <!-- content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/e3BkK/

Answer (score 1):

To always display a vertical scroll bar, you can use

```
#yourDivId {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If your contained content has a smaller height than `#yourDivId`, then the vertical scroll bar appears disabled.

If it has a bigger height, then the vertical scroll bar becomes enabled.

Comment: FYI, we had issues with IE and overflow-y: scroll (Scrolling using the mouse wheel simply wouldn't work w/ IE).  So we used this: http://pastebin.com/FW8Mjnfs

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: scroll` to the `body` element through CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/GMcdf/1/.

```
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```